# Mysql search table with value from different table

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have 2 different tables one for Items and another for a Search.

I want to be able to put in a word in the search table and have it be used with my items table to find any entries that match the search word.

How can I set it up to do it exactly this way?

```
SELECT * FROM [Items] WHERE ItemName LIKE '%keyword%'
```

How can I replace the `'%keyword%'` with the word that is in the Search table?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT * FROM Items i
LEFT JOIN search s
ON s.items.id = i.itemid
WHERE i.ItemName AND s.ItemName LIKE '%keyword%'
```